# Python - Compute the length of a path for a moving object

Tags: python, math

I am taking a university course on Scientific Programming. We are using the book *A primer on Scientific Programming with Python*. I am trying to do a lot of exercises to prepare myself for exam, because I experience it to be difficult to go from math to programming. I think it is bit to abstract. I am having trouble with exercise 3.10:

Compute the length of the path in a plane.

The total length of L from (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) to (x<sub>n-1</sub>, y<sub>n-1</sub>) is given by:

L = ∑<sub>i=1,...,n-1</sub> sqrt[ (x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>i-1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>i-1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> ]

I have to make a function pathlength(x, y) for computing L where (x, y) = (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>), (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>), ... , (x<sub>n-1</sub>, y<sub>n-1</sub>)

Then I have to test the function for a triangular path (1,1), (2,1), (1,2), (1,1)

I have been trying to figure it out. But I am having difficulties with the fact that it has to be a function for (x,y) but what I got until now is this:

```
from math import sqrt

def pathlength(x,y):
n = len(pts)
x = [pts[i][0] for i in range(n)]
y = [pts[i][1] for i in range(n)]
lv = [sqrt((x[i]-x[i-1])**2 + (y[i]-y[i-1])**2) for i in range (1,n)]
L = sum (lv)
return L
```

I do not know if this is the correct way.
But implementing my code outside a function I get this:

```
pts = [
(1,1),
(2,1),
(1,2),
(1,1),
]

n = len(pts)
x = [pts[i][0] for i in range(n)]
y = [pts[i][1] for i in range(n)]
lv = [sqrt((x[i]-x[i-1])**2 + (y[i]-y[i-1])**2) for i in range (1,n)]
L = sum (lv)
print lv
print L
```

Is there a way to solve this for (x,y), when entering points like this?

Comment: better make that range(1, n-1) or you'll have a problem, too.

Comment: @duffymo why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, I'll just leave this `numpy` solution here as well. Because if you are dealing with scientific programming, you will most likely have use of `numpy` at some point. At least you should know about it :)

```
import numpy as np
pts = [(0,0), (0,1), (3,1), (3,0)] # Corners of rectangle of height 1, length 3
apts = np.array(pts) # Make it a numpy array
lengths = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(apts, axis=0)**2, axis=1)) # Length between corners
total_length = np.sum(lengths)
```

Let's break it down.

Firt we get the squared differences between the x and y coordinates of each point.

```
np.diff(apts, axis=0)**2
```

What we get is a new array where the first column contains all `(x_i - x_(i-1))^2` and the second column the corresponding `(y_i - y_(i-1))^2`.

Now we calculate the actual squared distance, by summing the two columns in the previous array

```
np.sum(np.diff(apts, axis=0)**2, axis=1)
```

And the final step is of course just the square root, to get the length and not the squared length.

Comment: 3rd line: arr? perhaps apts?

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are lists of numbers themselves, you don't
need to calculate them inside the function anymore, you
can just use them. In that case your program would become:

```
from math import sqrt

def pathlength(x,y):
    n = len(x) 
    lv = [sqrt((x[i]-x[i-1])**2 + (y[i]-y[i-1])**2) for i in range (1,n)]
    L = sum(lv)
    return L

pts = [ (1,1), (2,1), (1,2), (1,1) ]

n = len(pts)
x = [pts[i][0] for i in range(n)]
y = [pts[i][1] for i in range(n)]

# Now call the function with the x and y that you prepared
# and print the result
l = pathlength(x, y)
print l
```

Comment: thank you very much, I did not see it beforehand, but now it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip function to fast converting 2-dimensional array to 2 vectors:

```
def pathlength(x,y):
    n = len(x)
    lv = [sqrt((x[i]-x[i-1])**2 + (y[i]-y[i-1])**2) for i in range(n)]
    L = sum(lv)
pts = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
x,y = zip(*pts)
print pathlength(x,y)
x = [1, 2, 1, 1]
y = [1, 1, 2, 1]
print pathlength(x,y)
```

When you learn numpy you also can write

```
m = numpy.array(pts)
x,y = m.T
```

Comment: Our book, does not say anything about the unzip functionality of the zip function But it is very nice to know that it exists. thank you very much. It could be helpfull for future usage.